# Can different ASP.NET websites share Forms Authentication if they're on the same server?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) states that you can share forms authentication across across websites that are on the same server.  Will this still work if the websites on the same server have completely different domain names?

Comment: It doesn't say anything in the article about domain name restrictions.

Comment: But doesn't the browser only send cookies up to the relevant domain?  So if I create an auth cookie on www.test.com and I go to www.fake.com, that auth cookie created on www.test.com won't be sent up to www.fake.com in the http request, thus, www.fake.com won't know that I logged into www.test.com.